# Как в laravel обрабатывать post запросы, с обращением к контроллеру?

Tags: laravel

Я реализую фронтенд react и мне нужно реализовать регистрацию по api. Я установил rout но вот как обратиться к контроллеру который регистрирует пользователя не могу понять как обратиться.
Моя реализация

```
Route::post('/registration', [
    'as' => Request::class, 'uses' => 'RegisterController@create'
]);
```

И пробовал идти вот так

```
Route::post('/registration', function(Request $request){
// И тут я встал в ступор
});
```

То есть я на эти роуты отправляю объекты, ну json а вот обратиться к контроллеру пока не понял как
При этом в первом случае у меня пишет `Class App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController does not exist`
Хотя он есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить в маршруте второй аргумент:

```
Route::post('/registration', 'RegisterController@create');
```

А в контроллере RegisterController.php сперва импортируйте класс `Request` строкой:

```
use Request;
```

А потом опишите метод create() примерно так *(в зависимости от ваших предпочтений)*:

```
public function create()
{
    // Получаете пост(или гет) данные
    $request = Request::all();

    // Передаёте эти данные в вашу модель(например, ваша модель React)
    React::create($request);

    // И перенаправляете браузер на главную
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Да я думал где надо менять json формат на array понял что в контроллере надо переписать